# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Jboss7 AS server startup issue

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I'm facing error while starting the JBOSS 7 AS server as below...

JBoss Bootstrap Environment
JBOSS_HOME: C:\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0
JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java

JAVA_OPTS: -client -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M

Error occurred during initialization of VM

```
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Does your system have enough free memory for the 1303 minimum JVM heap size you've set?  Try setting -Xms256m and see if it starts up.

Comment: Can you post what you did to get this to work as answer and close this thread?

Comment: @SureshKoya : Dave's Answer worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue. Based on above comments, I created an environment variable named
 `JAVA_OPTS`
with value
`-client -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms512M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M`

Hope this is more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I set env variable `JAVA_OPTS` with value:

```
-client -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms512M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
```

and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

Modify the file run.conf from /bin

```
-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

with this:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```